# Vertx - Multiple failureHandlers for the same route

Tags: vert.x

The question is simple: is it possible to have multiple failure handlers for one route?

```
router.route(HttpMethod.POST, "/test")
        .handler(LoggerHandler.create())
        .handler(ResponseTimeHandler.create())
        .failureHandler(MyCustomFailureHandler1.create())
        .failureHandler(MyCustomFailureHandler2.create());
```

I'm currently using vert.x version 4.0.2, and I can see that internally, every failure handler I create is added to a failureHandlers list, but when an error is thrown, the only failure handler executing is the first one specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the first failure handler (`MyCustomFailureHandler1.create()`), you have to call [RoutingContext#next()](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/RoutingContext.html#next--)

Documentation of `RoutingContext#next()` states:  "If next is not called for a handler then the handler should make sure it ends the response or no response will be sent".

See  TestCase here: [testMultipleSetFailureHandler](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/blob/b62341fe3256d289244b887173eec4a92360317d/vertx-web/src/test/java/io/vertx/ext/web/RouterTest.java#L2214)